# Replacing Honda Civic Taillight ?

Tags: honda, civic

I have a Honda Civic 2008 whose exterior plastic on one of the taillights was broken sometime ago. I duck taped it to keep it in place. The taillight bulb itself is good and functioning properly.

What options do I have in terms of doing this DIY? 
Is it possible to just replace the exterior plastic/glass?

Comment: Here is a good image of what the tail light assembly looks like. [Honda Parts Now.com](http://www.hondapartsnow.com/Page_Product/PartDetail.aspx?catalogID=75&productID=4&yearID=39&doorID=1&gradeID=6&areaID=2&transmissionID=7&originID=-1&colorLabelIDs=-1&colorLabelID=-1&sectionID=5&idAndImageID=14474%20947126&isBigPicture=False&pageName=Taillight%20-%20License%20Light)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually the glass is bonded on to the reflector unit, so you probably won't be able to buy the glass on its own - You'll have to buy a complete unit.

Your best bet is to ask around any scrapyards/junkyards in your area, see if they have any Civics in stock, as that would be considerably cheaper than a new unit from Honda.

A decent workshop manual should describe the removal/refitting procedure, most cars I've seen it is usually held in by 2 or 3 bolts and/or a couple of plastic clips.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to replace just the exterior plastic/glass, but the problem is finding it for a decent price.  Since your car is a 2008 (newer), it may be harder to find at a scrapyard.  If you can, then buy the part.  If not, you'll have to get the replacement from  Honda and probably pay an arm and a leg, but once you have the part, the actual replacement is not too difficult.